# Android Object Models

Tags: android

I've worked in software development for a number of years (10+) and am just starting to have a proper look at Android. From my current understanding, a GUI is built up of Activities (replacing Forms, etc) and each of those is treated almost like its own mini program since passing references to data is not the simplest approach, and those that are available aren't particularly nice.

Anyway, my current favoured approach to GUI development is to create an object model that contains all of the functions I want to provide and then I can build the GUI (or console, or server access, or whatever) to talk to that model via Interfaces. Individual forms may be passed cut down interfaces, and only partial parts of the model, that are used for that particular form. For me, this keeps the front end separate from the functionality and also abstracts away the implementation of the Object Model from the GUI. One advantage for me is that I can write a library to do something then stick on a java GUI, an android GUI, a console, whatever. In fact, I sometimes develop the functionality prior to developing any GUI.

Now, in Android this appears to be a trickier approach to take. I think I could achieve the same by serialising the model, and parts of it, and passing these around as strings but I'm not sure this is practical. I also can see that this wouldn't work if part of the model needed to callback to another part of the model that won't exist because it wasn't in the serialised section. ie, I have an object model that holds a list of data objects. I want to pass a data object to another Activity and if it gets edited at all, call back to the object model to enable it to do something else.

Am I able to write something to reuse my object models or does this approach just not work well with Android? If it does work, how? If not, what suitable alternatives can I use?

Comment: Without not too much experience on Android, one thing that gave me some model to follow, and try to find ways to expose it when having multiple Activities sharing same data, was [GlobalState](http://blog.tomgibara.com/post/126377651/global-application-state-in-android). As simple idea as it is, having your Activity destroyed all the time gave me some real headache at the very beginning.

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that but that was one of my "aren't particularly nice" options. I'm not keen on having globals. The whole approach I take is to decouple and then I use globals for Android, just don't feel comfortable with it. Obviously, if it's the only approach then I may have no choice.

Comment: Well it is possible to pass objects between activities using the fully qualified name of the object class as a name/value pair. This is not 100% type safe, but doable.

Comment: That's not a reference to an object though. That's a serialized clone of the object isn't it?

Comment: Hi Matt. Yes it is a clone, but then I prefer passing immutable objects in messages and adding a degree of indirection between the model and views.

Comment: Depends on what you're doing. It's ok for passing a value but if a reference is needed, because of callbacks, common resources, etc, then this approach may be a problem. You're going to need the fully qualified name anyway, so whether the object is referenced or not, you still need to have an understanding of the Model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to model Android development with desktop GUI or console mode development.

Rather, consider Web development.

Unless you've hopped on the `node.js` bandwagon, your Web app is not written in Javascript. However, a bunch of your GUI functionality will be implemented in Javascript (e.g., client-side validation, enforcing required fields before enabling the submit button). While you may have a rich object model for handling the bulk of your business logic, that will be on the server, in Java, Ruby, PHP, Perl, Python, or whatever. Web pages do not directly interact with that rich object model. And, each Web page stands alone, passing data to other pages only by relatively limited data in key-value pairs (`GET` parameters).

Android is, architecture-wise, a bit of a mash-up of desktop and Web development patterns. Activities are standalone entities, loosely coupled, as are Web pages. You don't pass model objects between activities, just as you don't pass model objects between Web pages.

This does not mean that you cannot have a rich object model. However, just as Web pages are going back to a central server to manipulate the Web app's rich object model, activities will need to reach back to a central store to manipulate your rich object model. And, just as Web pages tend to pass around identifiers of objects, your activities can pass around identifiers of objects, so each activity can then access the proper object from the central store.

Whether that central store is mediated by a `Service` or via some singleton is up to you and would depend some on what that rich object model was really supposed to represent.

Comment: ok, I can sort of see how that could work. I could remain using my object as a static at an application level, but have activities using a more generic interface to get data from it (like GET) rather than using the calls I provide. I can pass the intent to GET that data to the Activity and it can use the application to find it and work on it. I think this could be a workable approach. As an example, say open an activity with something like "GET account details for Kevin" and then the Application would have a "Retrieve account details function" that the sub-Activity calls with Kevin as an arg.

Comment: btw, I think you're right that the way I am looking and how I expressed it was for desktop development, but that wasn't really my intent. My real intent is to separate the business logic from the front end and I just hadn't considered the web style approach. Effectively I can keep my library model and wrap it with some retrieval code to work with Android.

Comment: @Matt_JD: "Effectively I can keep my library model and wrap it with some retrieval code to work with Android" -- yes. The biggest difference that I see is that you're passing around keys to a central (possibly static) collection vs. passing around objects proper.

Comment: Have to say, being someone who likes to reduce coupling (probably a bit too much) I really liked the idea of Android's approach but felt that practically it was limiting. I found your answer enlightening and my faith in the approach has been somewhat improved. I think it would be improved further if there were a way to capture the Intent to create an Activity and provide it with an interface to where it can find the "GET" function. The approach you identified does seem to couple an Activity to an Application so it isn't reusable. I could possibly overlook this though.

Comment: btw, I'm not ignoring accepting your answer. I'm just giving other people a chance and me a chance to try it out first. :)

Answer (score 0):

Matt... I have no idea why your question got me to thinking. So here is some nutty code:

Given an interface:

```
public interface ISayHello {
    public void SayHello();
}
```

A concrete class SayHello

```
public class SayHello implements ISayHello, Serializable {
    public void SayHello() {
        Log.d(Main.TAG,"hello");
    }
}
```

One can pass the fully qualified name of the interface in an intent as:

```
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                SayHello say= new SayHello();
                b.putSerializable("qprinstitute.crisis.ISayHello", say);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);
```

And cast the instance of the concrete class to the type (the interface) in the receiving activity as:

```
Intent i= getIntent();
if (i != null) {inBundle= i.getExtras();}
if (inBundle != null) {
    ISayHello say= (ISayHello)inBundle.getSerializable("qprinstitute.crisis.ISayHello");
    say.SayHello();
}
```

Which logs "hello". Cool!

Comment: Hi, I think this is just down to how interfaces and serialization work. It doesn't really solve my problem. This works because Log is static and so won't be tied to the instance of SayHello. The ISayHello that is deserialized by the Activity is not the same object as the original one that is created; it is a clone. I think that if you could get it so that the original SayHello opened a port or used a callback and whenever SayHello was called it would pass on data to the port or callback, you'd see that this wouldn't work. The clone would be rebuilt but wouldn't be referencing the same objects.

Comment: @Matt_JD ... It may not work for you. I was just envisioning say Recordset getData(); where getData() encapsulates the userID, password database and storedProcedure.

Comment: Yes, a bundled data type. I'm looking more for maintaining of functionality and allowing callbacks here though. I think the approach Commonsware fits best and I can think of a few tweaks that would maybe make it more how I like it. I may have a play and post my answer based on his when I have time.